# Revision of abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, vector-spaces, divisibility

Any advice on the best way to revise abstract algebra, topics for the exam include groups, rings, divisibility and factorisation, vector spaces and linear maps and inner product spaces??? please help
would u advise learning theorems etc by heart, working through examples? an advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps by "revise" you mean "review?"

Comment: There's a few terms that are probably from some country other than the U.S. One of them is "revise" (apparently equivalent, in this context, to "review"). Another is "doubt" as in "I have a doubt concerning . . ." (apparently equivalent to "I don't understand the justification for . . ."). I kind of like the "doubt" term, although I never heard it until I started on MSE.

Comment: revise: reread work done previously to improve one's knowledge of a subject, typically to prepare for an examination. (British)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples, yes, lots of them.

Exercises, yes, but choose them selectively.

Definitions, yes, all of them.

Theorems, all the statements, yes.

All the proofs, no, not all of them. The really easy ones, convince yourself that they're trivial and that you can do them whenever needed. For the ones that need a trick, internalize the trick (they're often reusable). For ones that you really like, and/or you think are important to understand, go ahead and memorize the proof, at least in outline form.

Pose questions to yourself as you progress, and if you can't answer them after a serious attempt, perhaps ask them here on MSE.

Also, make sure to choose a text (and possibly alternates) whose style of writing seem clear, appeals to you, and provides exercises that provoke interest.

Good luck!